# How to change strokeColor by custom gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I want to animate strokeColor of CAShapeLayer, but in CABasicAnimation I have two value (from and to). Is it only two color support while animation is fire? For example, on start I have `strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;`
then

```
CABasicAnimation *colorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
colorAnimation.duration            = 3.0; // "animate over 3 seconds or so.."
colorAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
colorAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;   // Remain stroked after the animation..
colorAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
colorAnimation.toValue   = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
colorAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
```

on half-way I have a dark purple color, but I need, for example, yellow color.

Is it possible to add custom gradient to CABasicAnimation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `CABasicAnimation`, but you can use a [`CAKeyframeAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to set intermediate values for your animation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *colorAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
colorAnimation.values               = @[(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
                                        (id)[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor],
                                        (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
colorAnimation.duration             = 3.0;  // "animate over 3 seconds or so.."
colorAnimation.repeatCount          = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
colorAnimation.removedOnCompletion  = NO;   // Remain stroked after the animation..
colorAnimation.fillMode             = kCAFillModeForwards;
colorAnimation.timingFunction       = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
```

If you want a "across the spectrum" sort of feel, you could do:

```
colorAnimation.values = @[(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
```

Or if you want more of a simple blue to red, but avoiding that really dark purple, you could do:

```
colorAnimation.values = @[(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
```

Lots of options.

Comment: @RostK. Obviously, this opens up tons of options. Updated my answer with two other examples.